# Failed to inject the dependency

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a learner of spring. I am trying to build a app using spring data jpa.

i have created a class something like below.

```
package com.myclass.projecttracker.main;

@Service
public class myDao {
    @Autowired
    TrackerCrudRepo trackerCrudRepo;
    public TrackerCrudRepo myclass(){
    return trackerCrudRepo; 
    }
}
```

and my spring boot application main class is as below.

```
    package com.mindtree.projecttracker.main;
    @RestController
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myclass.projecttracker.main"})
    public class Parser2 {

    ResourceDetailExtractor resourceDetailExtractor = new ResourceDetailExtractor(); 

        public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException{
            SpringApplication.run(Parser2.class, arg);

        }

        @RequestMapping("/")
        void home() throws IOException {
            //custom implimentation
        myDao MyDao = new myDao();
        TrackerCrudRepo trackerCrudRepo = MyDao.myclass();

        }


package com.myclass.projecttracker.model;

@Repository("myRepo")
public interface TrackerCrudRepo extends CrudRepository<ResourceData, Long> {

}
```

When u run this app it will throw an error

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field trackerCrudRepo in com.myclass.projecttracker.main.myDao required a bean of type 'com.myclass.projecttracker.model.TrackerCrudRepo' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myclass.projecttracker.model.TrackerCrudRepo' in your configuration.

Can anyone please help me identifying the solution to this situation

Comment: I don't see a `TrackerCrudRepo` class in your code, or any `@Bean`s defined.

Comment: is `TrackerCrudRepo` defined as `@Component`?

Comment: updated my question with `TrackerCrudRepo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TrackerCrudRepo` is inside package `com.myclass.projecttracker.model` but you have declared `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myclass.projecttracker.main"})` to scan for your component.

So you need to either  move `TrackerCrudRepo` to package `com.myclass.projecttracker.main` or change `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myclass.projecttracker.main"})` to `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myclass.projecttracker"})`

Comment: When i try this i am getting `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'trackerCrudRepo'`

Comment: you need to add @EnableJpaRepositories in your configuration.

Comment: Can you please tell me in which class i need to use this?

Comment: in class Parser2.

Comment: No Luck with @EnableJpaRepositories

Comment: try adding @Configuration and replace "@EnableJpaRepositories" with "@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"package_where_TrackerCrudRepo"})"

Answer (score 1):

myDao is annotated with @service so spring will take care of it's creation

You should remove

```
myDao MyDao = new myDao();
```

in Parser2 class, marked it with @Autowired annotation, spring will take care 
of it instantiation in Parser2 class

```
@Autowired 
myDao MyDao
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. But this doesnt solve my problem with the errors

Comment: i have test it my own machine and it's working, can you please `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myclass"})` instead of  `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myclass.projecttracker.main"})` use in your Parser2 class